# DBT: Encountered an error while generating catalog: 'dtype'

Tags: dbt

I am using dbt version 0.19.1.

I have a pipeline that automatically runs `dbt docs generate` whenever i push some changes to my git repository.
From a certain point in time, pipelines started to fail with these error message:

```
Running with dbt=0.19.1
Found 776 models, 0 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 359 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 145 sources, 0 exposures

14:44:45 | Concurrency: 8 threads (target='default')
14:44:45 | 
14:45:07 | Done.
14:45:07 | Building catalog
Encountered an error while generating catalog: 'dtype'
dbt encountered 1 failure while writing the catalog
```

The problem is that I have many models and changes happening in the source code and it is not easy to understand from this message where the error is coming from.
If I check the logs files in the logs folder they are very messy, containing debug information from all the threads, i cannot find the source of the issue.

Is there a way to understand where this issue is coming from?
Is it possible to better debug dbt docs generate command?

Thank you all for your replies in advance!

Francesco

Comment: what vesion of python is your ci pipeline using? it might be worth adding a step after this fails to print out the logs the error. like `tail -n500 logs/dbt.log`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to better debug dbt docs generate command?

To better debug the issue you can use

```
dbt --debug docs generate
```

That *will* contain the debug information from all the threads, but it should also include a stack trace from where the error was raised.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Josh, adding another point to look for the error.

I suggest who have the same issues and has thousands of rows of logs like me to look for the string "*Error while running*" in the debug logs to find the place where the exception should have raised.

Hopes this could help someone else.